# Merge strings from separate files into single XML document

Tags: c#, xml

I am receiving XML data through a socket, the data is of type string and is being written into  a file on my desktop like so:

```
while (true)
{
    int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
    Console.WriteLine("DATA RESPONSE {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));
    String stringToWrite = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringToWrite))
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"c://temp//Tain//" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyymmddHHMMssfff") + ".xml", stringToWrite);
    }
}
```

Now the issue that I'm having is that the xml document is split into separate files leaving me something like this per file received:

```
 <someNode attribute, attribute etc. etc.
```

Basically, start node is in document no.1 and end node is in doc no.5 or no.10 and I have to concatenate the strings from multiple files to create a whole XML document!

The only information I have about beginning and ending of an xml is a new line which separates previous from next new xml. Problem with this is sometimes, more often than not, the new xml string begins in the same file where the previous ended!

I have no idea what my approach should be and the internet has not been very helpful with advice or examples, it would be helpful if someone shun a light!

**UPDATE**
As per Panagiotis' advice I was able to add all content to a single file, that way all the xmls are in one place separated by new line break like so:

```
 <somenode atr atr etc etc></somenode>

 <somenode atr atr etc etc></somenode>
```

How can I split those xmls into new separate files one file for each of these, keeping in mind that somenodes are always the same?

Comment: `Receive` doesn't return a *file*, it fills a buffer with the part of the file sent by the server. Instead of writing each buffer to a different file, append the contents to the same file. You could use `File.AppendText` although a better idea would be to create a single file stream/streamwriter and write to it until the server finishes

Comment: XML files typically start with an XML declaration `<?xml...`. If you have no other way of detecting that one file ended and another started, you can inspect `stringToWrite` for an XML declaration and write to the stream only the contents up to the declaration

Comment: Is it possible to initially store all contents in a single file and than separate different xmls based on their begin and end node, all of the xml content starts and ends with specific node so I thought about storing all into one file and than split into new files ones that will contain only one complete xml, is something like that possible? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: I would tell, problem is in lower layer - in case of repeat - isn't it same packet resent, but not recognized properly ? And I think you cannot fix such a problems on XML level in general unless you add some check marks, hashes, etc. to recognize if you have proper block.

Comment: Storing into one file or simply keeping the stream in MemoryStream and writing out separate files for each complete xml node is the straightforward way to do it. This is called Xml parsing and is not an exact science, but if you know encoding and the specific node the content starts and ends with then on each StringToWrite see if IndexOf("<someNode") > -1 and if it is start a new Stream from that index, then look for IndexOf("</someNode>") and either put the entire StringToWrite into the stream and wait for the next one or put the substring to that index in the StringToWrite and write to file.

Comment: @TheMikeInNYC Thanks! I understand this in theory, but haven't used memoryStream yet, is there any example I can take a look at so I can understand the logic?